# PL/SQL-code: Create a function get_return_date.

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

A person rents a car today and for 7 days. The function will return: date + hours + minutes. Thanks in advance! : )

```
create or replace function get_return_date(
p_days in number)
return varchar2
is 
begin
return to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI') + p_days;
end;
/
```

Comment: Why do I get a error when a take

Comment: Error if try to select get_return_date(7) from dual;

Comment: Is there some specific reason you are returning string instead of a date?

Comment: Is it the same answer with date?

Comment: I tried with to_date and then I did get the date back, not the time.

Comment: Sysdate function returns date and time. I asked why you are returning string instead of date because novice developers sometimes convert date to string because they think that is the correct way to format date to some specific format. It isn't - date should always be return as date, and whoever is responsible for displaying that date should format it. This is not the case if layer that is calling your function does not support Oracle's dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the days *before* converting to a string:

```
create or replace function get_return_date(
p_days in number)
return varchar2
is 
begin
    return to_char(sysdate + p_days,'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI');
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot : ): ): )

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because you need to do the math before you convert to a string. Essentially, this is what you are telling the compiler:

> "Monday" + 2

That doesn't make any sense in math terms, so it throws an error. the `sysdate` is actually already a number, so you can add another number to it. Then, you use your `to_char` to convert that single value into a formatted string like this:

```
create or replace function get_return_date(
p_days in number)
return varchar2
is 
begin
return to_char(sysdate + p_days,'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI');
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it make sense to me now! : ) : )

Comment: No problem. If one of these answers solved your problem, please mark it as accepted to indicate to other users your issue was resolved.